# How easy to learn flex for a java developer

Tags: java, apache-flex

Is flex similar to java programming model? How easy for a java developer to learn flex? Please suggest.

Comment: Yes it is easy.But you need to ask program specific questions here not general questions

Comment: Thank you and Sorry about it, is flex similar to java programming model.

Comment: Refer my answer for details..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop in Flex with the existing tools used to develop Java. You can also develop Flex applications with the free command-line tools included in the SDK, with Adobe Flex Builder (an Eclipse plug-in), or most recently, with IntelliJ IDEA 8.
Flex provides a stateful environment in which data is loaded from the client. The programming model is more like developing a desktop client than Hypertext Markup Language (HTML) programming, which makes the programming model feel familiar to anyone who has done Java Swing programming.
Flex is programmed using a combination of MXML, a UI markup language similar to Extensible Markup Language (XML), and Adobe ActionScript, an object-oriented scripting language. This combination makes programming Flex similar to programming with Java, because you can use the familiar object-oriented concepts.
An ideal way to set up your development environment is to have the Flex application built right in your web deployment directory. That way, you do not need to re-deploy your application after every build: A simple browser refresh reflects the latest changes. Developing with Flex and BlazeDS is fairly productive as a result.
To simply answer your question is the programming model same YES it is somewhat same to an extent.

Again it is not recommended you ask these type of questions here.Cheers happy coding!!

Comment: Accept it if it is helpful..